# Fixing a module with incorrect namespacing for Patch 6788

Tags: extensions, patches, supee-6788

I am trying to fix the admin route issue for a 3rd party module, as required for patch 6788.

The module code sits in a directory directly below 'community' rather than in a namespace directory

i.e

```
community/TheModule
```

Upon changing the admin router in the config xml to the following,

```
  <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <themodule_admin before="Mage_Adminhtml">Themodule_Adminhtml</themodule_admin>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

the admin routes no longer work, and I can see that this is because the filename Magento is odd

i.e. with debugging logs in the from the _validateControllerClassName method in Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard I can see Magento is looking for files in paths like the following

```
app/code//TheModule/Adminhtml/controllers/
```

Ideally the module should be sitting under a namespace, but is there a quick fix I can apply to this module in order to get it patched for 6788?

Comment: You might want to consider mentioning the basic code you started with. You provided a solution that didn't work but it is not possible to see what changed in relation to the earlier code

Comment: Didn't want to go pasting the third party modules code in, 2 reasons, not sure on whether sharing their code is allowed, and second, didn't want it to be a name and shame. So I just had to type up a hypothetical module, with the relevant parts. Ultimately, the problem was the module was not coded correctly, so I had to move the module to a namespace, and make a lot of manual edits to it to fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

So there didn't seem to be a quick fix. Instead copied the module to a namespace directory, updating the XML as required.

Mainly ran into problems because the module was use 'new' to create classes in some places, and referencing a lot of constants using modulename::constant